# Can apache return a JSON response to 404 and other errors?

Tags: json, apache

There is plenty of documentation on how to customize the 404 (and other error) response pages, but they all result in an HTML response to the client. If the client is an application making REST calls the HTML is useless and does not fit the Accept request header of "application/json".

Is there a way to customize not just the content, but also the headers that are returned for 404 and similar errors? Even better, would like to write code that examines the request header Accept value and returns a response in the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path_to_file.json
```

the headers should be the ones defined in mime/types so the answer should be application/json

regarding the Accept value you can parse the request headers and set the response accordingly